# how to move button to another frame in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

There are two frames contain buttons.

When does click button in Left frame, clicked button move to right frame.

How to move button to another frame in pyqt?

```
def create_widget(self):

    left_frame = QFrame(self)
    left_frame.setFixedWidth(300)
    left_frame.setFixedHeight(400)
    left_frame.move(0, 0)


    for x in range(10):
        btn = QPushButton('button', left_frame)
        btn.setFixedWidth(50)
        btn.setFixedHeight(20)
        btn.move(5, 0+(30*x))
        btn.clicked.connect(self.click_btn_add)


    right_frame = QFrame(self)
    right_frame.setFixedWidth(300)
    right_frame.setFixedHeight(400)
    right_frame.move(400, 0)


def click_btn_add(self):
    # How to move button to another frame?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of a widget is relative to the parent, and that is clear since the buttons have as their parent a `self.left_frame` and their positions are relative to it. If you want it to move to the other `QFrame` you just have to set the other parent to the other `QFrame` with `setParent()` and make it visible with `show()` (when changing parent the widget is hidden). To obtain the button in the slot we will use `sender()` that returns the object that issued the signal, and in this case it is the button. In the following I will make that each time you press the button it will move to the other `QFrame`:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.create_widget()

    def create_widget(self):
        self.left_frame = QFrame(self)
        self.left_frame.setFixedSize(300, 400)
        self.left_frame.move(0, 0)

        self.right_frame = QFrame(self)
        self.right_frame.setFixedSize(300, 400)
        self.right_frame.move(400, 0)

        for x in range(10):
            btn = QPushButton('button', self.left_frame)
            btn.setFixedSize(50, 20)
            btn.move(5, 30*x)
            btn.clicked.connect(self.click_btn_add)

    def click_btn_add(self):
        btn = self.sender()
        new_parent = self.right_frame if btn.parent() == self.left_frame else self.left_frame
        btn.setParent(new_parent)
        btn.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Always Thanks!! eyllanesc!!